# Can't set volume to more than 100% in Odin

Tags: sound, release-odin

I liked that you could set a volume to more than 100% in the Sound settings in the previous versions - it's sometimes useful when you for example play a YouTube video which has rather low volume. Can I have something similar in the Odin release?